Adyen card form not rendering on test server
I am using adyen to create a payment form
i configured the card on test environment
new Card(checkout, {
      autoFocus: true,
      enableStoreDetails: true,
      environment: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ADYEN_ENVIRONMENT,
    }).mount("#card-container");

export const getPaymentConfig = ({
  id,
  sessionData,
  onSubmit,
  onFail,
  onError,
}) => ({
  session: {
    id: id,
    sessionData: sessionData,
  },
  // Change to 'live' for the live environment.
  environment: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ADYEN_ENVIRONMENT,
  locale: "fr-FR",
  countryCode: "FR",
  clientKey: import.meta.env.VITE_APP_CLIENT_KEY,
  analytics: {
    enabled: true,
  },
  onPaymentCompleted: onSubmit,
  onPaymentFailed: onFail,
  onError: onError,
});

it is working just fine with my react vite dev server, but i deploy it on the test server it is not.
I already checked the cors and all good
this are the warning on the console :
console warning
and the adyen API call is working :
Adyen success response
Do you guys have any ideas how can I fix this, noting that i am deploying the test server and the enviroment should test ?

I don't see anything wrong with the code, looking at your console, I did notice the following statement:

Check that the clientKey is created against the right endpoint and that the list of "Allowed Origins" contains the domain of your website (test server).

According to the Client-Side Authentication documentation, the client-key import.meta.env.VITE_APP_CLIENT_KEY is bound to a specific origin.
I'd double-check to see whether the list of "Allowed Origins" contains the domain of your website. Probably, your localhost:8080 has been whitelisted, but not the domain of your test server.

Login in https://ca-test.adyen.com/ where you've created your API keys.

Go to Developers > API credentials, and select the API credential for your 'Web Drop-in' or 'Web Components' integration, f.e. ws@Company.[YourCompanyAccount].

Under "Allowed origins", enter your domain (of your test server) and select Add.

Select Save changes! It takes a few seconds for new allowed origins to become available for your application.


Hope that helped!

thanks for your answer but i am sure that my test server is in the Allowed Origins

Is the import.meta.env.VITE_APP_CLIENT_KEY (and import.meta.env.VITE_APP_ADYEN_ENVIRONMENT == TEST) populated on the test server?

Yes, 100%. I am actually build locally and copying the build with scp.

I'm making some educated guesses here at this point, the problem seems related to the server. I'll need more information, could you update and post your configuration file of your frontend and backend? Could there be an issue with the way the URL is specified, e.g. 127.0.0.1:3000vs localhost:3000
